# Django remove duplicates from queryset

Tags: python, django, orm

i want to remove duplicates in relative fields, my queryset example:

```
example = models.Object.objects.values('name', 'photo__name', 'url', 'photo__url').distinct()
```

`if name == photo__name and url == photo_url` i need to delete one of them, how can i do this with Django ORM or i need to iterate through queryset?

Comment: By 'delete' you mean removing the field from the returned queryset, or modify the existing database record?

Comment: i mean remove from returned queryset

Comment: this may be useful Entry.objects.extra(where=["foo='a' OR bar = 'a'", "baz = 'a'"])  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Answer (score 14):

If you are using **PostgreSQL**, check out the [Django docs on `distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

> On *PostgreSQL only*, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply...
>
> When you specify field names, you must provide an `order_by()` in the QuerySet, and the fields in `order_by()` must start with the fields in `distinct()`, in the same order.

Thus, in your example, you can remove duplicates on certain fields by using:

```
.order_by('photo__name', 'photo__url').distinct('photo__name', 'photo__url')
```

Comment: i use MySQL, i can't use fields in distinct

Answer (score 0):

To reference fields of model in filtering you can use Django ORM `F` function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

But i guess you cannot delete *one of them* :) You got to decide *which one* you want to delete

**UPDATE**

Look when you filter like `Object.objects.filter(photo__name='something')` you filter Object table by **related** photo name. So you dealing with join over two tables. If you want to exclude objects with name = related photo name you should do something like this

```
from django.db.models import F
Object.objects.exclude(name=F('photo__name'))
```

Is that useful?

Comment: if name == photo__name, i need to remove photo__name and if url == photo__url remove photo__url

Comment: Answers query selects only Objects with name different to related photo name. If you need something else you should specify models and input/output for example.